# Pulling data into a select option in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pull data from a different table into a select tag where the user can choose which program a certain course belongs to. I am getting an error of `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\IRMS\resources\views\courses\create.blade.php)`. How can I achieve this so that when I click on the `Add Course` button, it will give me the form iI can select the program code from.?

My code below:

**index.blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p><a href="." class="btn btn-outline-dark">Go Back</a></p>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Courses</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <p><a href="/home/courses/create" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Add Course</a></p>
                    @if (count($courses)> 0 )
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Program Code</th>
                                <th>Course Code</th>
                                <th>Course Name</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            @foreach ($courses as $course)
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>{{$course->program_code}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$course->course_code}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$course->course_name}}</td>
                                    <td>Edit</td>
                                    <td>Delete</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                    @else
                        <p>No Courses found!</p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('inc.sadmin-navbar')
@endsection
```

**create blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p><a href="." class="btn btn-outline-dark">Go Back</a></p>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Add New Course</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {!! Form::open(['action'=>'CoursesController@store', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
                        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                            {{Form::label('program_name', 'Program Name')}}
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @foreach ($programs as $program)
                                    {{Form::select('{{$program->id}}', ['{{$program->program_code}}'], null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick Program'])}}
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                            {{Form::submit('Add Program', ['class'=>'btn btn-success'])}}
                        </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('inc.sadmin-navbar')
@endsection
```

**courses controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Course;
use App\Program;

class CoursesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $courses = Course::all();
        return view('courses.index')->with('courses', $courses);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $programs = Program::all();
        return view('courses.create')->with('programs', $programs);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**programs controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Program;
// use App\CSE;

class ProgramsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $programs = Program::all();
        return view('programs.index')->with('programs', $programs);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('programs.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'program_name' => 'required',
            'program_code' => 'required'
        ]);

        $program = new Program;
        $program->program_name = $request->input('program_name');
        $program->program_code = $request->input('program_code');
        $program->save();

        return redirect('home/programs');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $program = Program::find($id);
        // $courses = CSE::all();
        return view('programs.software.index')->with('program', $program);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $program = Program::find($id);
        return view('programs.edit')->with('program', $program);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'program_name' => 'required',
            'program_code' => 'required'
        ]);

        $program = Program::find($id);
        $program->program_name = $request->input('program_name');
        $program->program_code = $request->input('program_code');
        $program->save();

        return redirect('home/programs');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $program = Program::find($id);
        $program->delete();

        return redirect('home/programs');
    }
}
```

Comment: everything inside `{{ ... }}` is PHP. `{{ }}` gets replaced with an echo statement ... this is not valid: `{{ ... {{ ... }} ... }}`  ... also that loop is creating new select tags, not adding options to a select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this also

```
$programs = Program::all();
$select = [];
foreach($programs as $program){
    $select[$program->id] = $program->program_code;
}
return view('programs.index', compact(['programs','select'));
```

```
 {!! Form::select('program', $select, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

or

```
@foreach ($programs as $program)
     {{Form::select($program->id, [$program->program_code], null, ['placeholder'=>'Pick Program'])}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: the first code gives an error of `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: it will $program->id.typing mistake

Comment: what is row name of your course code?? is it program_code or course_code or code?? just give this on that foreach($programs as $program){
    $select[$program->code] = $program->program_code;
}

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `{{}}` inside php `form::select` .

Try replacing the following lines .

```
 @foreach ($programs as $program)
     {{Form::select('{{$program->id}}', ['{{$program->program_code}}'], null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick Program'])}}
@endforeach
```

With this one : :

```
 @foreach ($programs as $program)
     {{Form::select($program->id, [$program->program_code], null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick Program'])}}
@endforeach
```

Try this and let me know, if you have any issues.

Comment: i get an issue of that it doesn't register that i have selected a value from the drop down so it doesn't submit

Answer (score 0):

remove {{ }} in your code:

```
{{Form::select('{{$program->id}}', ['{{$program->program_code}}'], null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick Program'])}}
```

it just is:
    $list_program is an array contain [program_id => program_code]

```
 {!! Form::select('program_id', $list_program, null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick Program'])!!}
```